# Reference request for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

The highest power of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$ is give by $p^{\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)}$

I am fully aware of how to prove this but I don't have space to prove it in my dissertation. Therefore I need to reference it but I can't find it anywhere. I thought it would be easy to find as it's such a well known fact. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Comment: The proof is a few lines, so I'm surprised you're closed enough to your length limit that you can't afford the proof, especially since appendices are often exempted. It's also an obvious enough result you might just be able to state it, but ask your supervisor (who might know a reference anyway).

Comment: @JaneDoé Thanks! Legendre 1830 is the right reference, then.

Comment: I never knew it was a formula of Legendre. Now I have found it easily.